How to make Movesense communicate with Nordic nRF52832 board with BLE?
I want to collect data from Movesense with an nRF52832 board through BLE.
First, I tried to connect with Movesense device with nRF Connect mobile application, where I can see the Heart Rate Service, Battery Service, and an Unknown Service, which contains a Notify Characteristic and one with Write properties.
My idea was that I need to find what to "write" to this characteristic, in order to subscribe to the specific sensor from which I want to retrieve data. This attempt was unsuccessfull.. and after more research in documentation I found out that the only way to make the Movesense device communicate with another device (or nRF Connect application I guess because it doesn't use the same libraries that the client applications of Movesense use) is to follow the CustomGATTService example.
My questions are:

If anyone has ever done this, if there is any other example or guidance available, because I don't think that the documentation is very clear,
Is my first assumption correct that nRF Connect Application cannot subscribe to the sensors easily as the Showcase app does, and the only solution is the creation of a custom service ?

I have followed this example: gatt-sensordata-sample
Specifically, updated the firmware with this zip file, and experimented with the WebClient in Chrome. Also, I have tried to insert the same bytearray in the write characteristic in nRF Connect  as I see the code does in this example ([1,99,"Meas/Acc/13"]), so that I subscribe in the acceleration sensor but with no result. (I type it as text utf-8). My conclusion is that this doesn't work as I hoped so i have to try the custom gatt service: custom-gatt-service-sample
and see what happens, but I was hoping for some clarification on the process or any guidance.
Thank you in advance!

The recommended way to communicate with the Movesense sensor from non-MDS compatible devices, is to use the simplified protocol described in the gatt_sensordata_app -sample. The sample comes with simple python and WebBLE clients, and the firmware source code (GATTSensorDataClient.cpp) contains a small description of the protocol.
Full Disclaimer: I work with the Movesense team

Do you know why I also see another Service with uuid 0xFDF3 which is not declared anywhere in the Code? Is this normal or have I done something wrong when I downloaded the code?

That one is the Whiteboard communication service (see: https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Files/Specification/Assigned_Numbers.pdf?id=3), which is always present in the Movesense sensors.
